# Perl: does long package name affects performance in resolution?

Tags: performance, perl, package

Suppose I have two packages defined(and both are perl classes and objects)

```
package FooRecord;
```

and

```
package FooBarHelloWorldRecord;
```

.
Will there be a performance difference when instances of above classes access their methods?
I am suggested that "long package name" will cause performance difference as perl does string comparisons of names during method resolution.

```
my $fooRecord = new FooRecord();  
$fooRecord->getFooData();

my $fooWorldRecord = new FooBarHelloWorldRecord();  
$fooWorldRecord->getWorldData();
```

Since there will be name resolution in above method calls, first one(due to shorter name) will exhibit better performance than second package name method call.

Speculation: Does perl not keep hash value of package names and does comparisons with them(internally)?

Comment: If long package names are your worst performance problem, you don't have a performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does make a difference:

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

package Foo {
   use Class::Tiny;
}

package FooButMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchLonger {
   use Class::Tiny;
}

package FooBut::So::So::So::So::So::So::So::So::Much::Deeper {
   use Class::Tiny;
}

cmpthese -1, {
  'short' => q{ Foo->new },
  'long'  => q{ FooButMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchMuchLonger->new },
  'deep'  => q{ FooBut::So::So::So::So::So::So::So::So::Much::Deeper->new },
}

__END__
         Rate  deep  long short
deep  45510/s    --  -12%  -19%
long  51692/s   14%    --   -8%
short 56366/s   24%    9%    --
```

Personally this isn't a way I'd choose to optimize. I'd generally favour longer, more descriptive class names.

Comment: The only reason the difference is that noticeable is that the code does practically nothing *except* name resolution.

Comment: If you check the Class::Tiny docs (and source code) you'll see that these examples are actually doing quite a bit more than just name resolution. They are, for example, blessing a hashref, and doing some argument handling (even though I don't pass any additional arguments to the constructor - the argument handling is still there in `Class::Tiny::Object::new`), etc.